# Можно ли захватить и использовать количество кликов по кнопке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу привязать событие к кнопке - шестой клик по ней. Это возможно?

Answer (score 6):

Конечно, возможно

Сделаем все по модному с декораторами ( функцией декоратором )

```js
// можно еще конктест передавать, но это если оч надо this
const callAfterTimes = (fn, times)=> {
  function decoratedFn(...args) {
    decoratedFn.callTimes++;
    if(decoratedFn.callTimes === times) {
      fn(...args);
      // обнуляем
      decoratedFn.callTimes = 0;
    }
  }
  decoratedFn.callTimes = 0;
  
  return decoratedFn
}

const button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
button[0].onclick = callAfterTimes(() => {
  alert('Алерт каждые 6 кликов');
}, 6);
button[1].onclick = callAfterTimes(() => {
  alert('Алерт каждые 3 клика');
}, 3);
```

```html
<button>Нажми на меня 6 раз</button>
<br><br>
<button>Нажми на меня 3 раза</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Нет ничего невозможного.

```js
let clicks = 0;
const onClick = _ => {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    if(clicks == 6) alert("yahooo 6 times clicked bruh");
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Comment: Используется глобальная переменная, что делает невозможным использование нескольких кнопок

Comment: @AntonShchyrov В вопросе нету условия про 500000 кнопок.Вообще нету условия .Плюсь данный код занимает 6 строки если что.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего завести data-параметр в самой кнопке

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('button').click(function() {
    const el = $(this);
    let cnt = el.data('clicks');
    if (!cnt)
      cnt = 1;
     else
       cnt++;
    if (cnt % 6 === 0) {
      console.log('Click ' + el.text());
      cnt = 0;
    }
    el.data('clicks', cnt);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test1</button>
<button>Test2</button>
```

Или через плагины

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  delayedClick: function(func, delay) {
    if (!delay)
      return this.click(func);
      
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).data({
        cnt: delay,
        cur: 0
      });
    }).click(function() {
      const el = $(this);
      let cur = el.data('cur') + 1;
      if (cur % el.data('cnt') === 0) {
        func.call(this);
        cur = 0;
      }
      el.data('cur', cur);
    });
  }
});

jQuery(function($) {
  $('button').delayedClick(function() {
    console.log('Clicked ' + $(this).text());
  }, 3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test1</button>
<button>Test2</button>
```